# Отправить данные через POST (fetch) JS

Tags: javascript, api, post, url

Всем привет.Не могу понять почему не уходит пост запрос. Пересмотрел несколько видео, и статей на эту тему. Вроде бы делаю как написано в них, но получаю ошибку.

Задача у меня такая, есть некий аналог соц.ленты, с базовым URL - `http://146.185.154.90:8000/blog/teddy@gmail.com`.

На сервере уже есть какое то имя и фамилия(получаю из через GET запрос и вывожу и на страницу), при желание мне нужно изменять их с помощью POST запроса и так же выводить на страницу.

Эндпоинт:
`POST /profile Отправляете данные: firstName: текст, не должен быть пустым lastName: текст, не должен быть пустым`

Я создал универсальную функцию:

```
const requestData = async (method, url, data = null) => {
   const res = await fetch(url, {
      method: method,
      headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
       },
      body: data
   })

   if(!res.ok) {
      throw new Error(`${url}: ${res.status}`)
   }
   return await res.json();
}
```

Беру данные через форму:

```
const form = document.querySelector('#change-name');

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
   e.preventDefault();
   const formData = new FormData(form);
   console.log(formData)

   const obj = {};
   formData.forEach((value, key) => {
      obj[key] = value;
   })

   let json = JSON.stringify(obj);
   console.log(json)

   requestData('POST', BASE_URL + '/profile', formData)
      .then( response => console.log(response))
})
```

В Network-е в Headers (Request payload) получаю вот это:

`------WebKitFormBoundarywjdJ2mFcpxCZcUBy Content-Disposition: form-data; name="firstName"`

`Yuriy ------WebKitFormBoundarywjdJ2mFcpxCZcUBy Content-Disposition: form-data; name="lastName"`

`asc ------WebKitFormBoundarywjdJ2mFcpxCZcUBy--`

Но в Response приходит ошибка: `{error: "Request should have "firstName" and "lastName" values!"`

Так же в дальнейшем нужно создавать и отправлять постына сервер, эндпоинты
`POST /posts Отправляете данные: message: текст, не должен быть пустым`
Пытался использовать туже универсальную функцию, ничего не выходит.

Есть подозрения что я не правильно отправляю сами данные на сервер, вот здесь:

```
const obj = {};
   formData.forEach((value, key) => {
      obj[key] = value;
   })

   let json = JSON.stringify(obj);
   console.log(json)
```

**Объясните что я не так делаю,и где может быть ошибка?**

P.S. Сижу с этой проблемой не один день уже.
HTML форма выглядит вот так:

```
<!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
         <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
               <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Авторизация</h5>
               <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
               <!-- Form -->
               <form id="change-name">
                  <div class="mb-3">
                     <label for="name-user" class="form-label">Имя</label>
                     <input type="text" name="firstName" class="form-control" id="name-user" aria-describedby="name-help">
                     <div id="name-help" class="form-text">Введите ваше имя</div>
                   </div>

                   <div class="mb-3">
                     <label for="lastname" class="form-label">Фамилия</label>
                     <input type="text" name="lastName" class="form-control" id="lastname-user">
                   </div>

                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="change-btn">Изменить</button>
               </form>
            </div>
         </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Сервер выдает вот это(это то что нужно изменять при желание):

```
{
   "_id": "600fc9d49d06ce06be995bc6",
   "email": "teddy@gmail.com",
   "firstName": "John",
   "lastName": "Doe"
}
```

Comment: Покажите серверную часть и html

Comment: сначала нужно определиться, посылаешь ли ты json, и поэтому указываешь `'Content-Type': 'application/json` или посылаешь `formData` передавая ее в функцию. А также, что может принимать сервер, json или formadata

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Добавил в вопрос

Comment: @Grundy Не совсем понял ваш комментарий, хотелось бы более развернутого ответа.

Comment: @Yuriy, в каком формате сервер ждет данные?

Comment: @Grundy подозреваю что в формате строки, если вы это имеете в виду. Я только изучаю работу с сервером  поэтому не могу точно сказать

Comment: Сервер ты сам писал? Или где-то есть документация? :)

Comment: @Grundy документации нету, это вообще контрольная работа была. Нам дали просто url и endpoint-ы. Задача была отработать работу с post и get запросами.

Comment: то есть сервер тоже ты пишешь?

Comment: @Grundy нет, я же написал выше что нам дали просто url

Comment: Тогда почему ты решил написать `headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
       },` в одном месте и `const formData = new FormData(form);` в другом?

Comment: @ Grundy я так понимаю что должно быть что-то одно, но я пробовал так. Когда я писал не через форму, проблема оставалась, выходила ошибка в response. Если можете объяснить прошу то сделать, а не ходить вокруг да около))

Comment: Уже было указано, что нужно смотреть что именно должен принимать сервер json или formdata, и в зависимости от этого либо устанавливать content-type и передавать json, либо отправлять formData, сейчас у тебя все в куче и как правильно неизвестно ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Также кроме тебя никто не знает, что именно нужно серверу.